# React Native - Use cookies to authenticate in WebView

Tags: android, ios, react-native, cookies, webview

So I've been provided a couple of API's for a React Native application.
One endpoint is for authentication and it returns a cookie which allows access to other API's.

The cookie has the following structure:

```
{"auth":"ok","instance":"private","cookies":{"SSOsess":"300|c6dc6d70vfvbf0891004364665f24b77","RTBk":"300|451706342c67a37dfe5dede0b5d22469","ph03RPNCiscoASA":"application.api.urlweb.com","ph04RPNCiscoASA":"application.client.urlweb.com"}}
```

After a bit of formatting the cookie is ready to be sent and looks like this:

```
SSOsess=300%7Cc6dc6d70vfvbf0891004364665f24b77; RTBk=300%7C451706342c67a37dfe5dede0b5d22469;
ph03RPNCiscoASA=application.api.urlweb.com;
ph04RPNCiscoASA=application.client.urlweb.com;
```

The are some `WebView`'s inside the React Native application that access some restricted parts of a website that uses some of the API's initially provided.

How can I send the cookie to the `WebView`? I know React Native has some attributes that could be used to inject cookies into the WebView such as `injectedJavaScript` or `injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded` but what exactly should those attributes contain?

I've tried sending it the following way but it does not work:

```
<WebView source={{ uri: 'http://urlweb.com' }}
               style={{width: 600, height: 400}}
               injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded={jsInjectedCode}
/>
```

where

```
jsInjectedCode = 'document.cookie = '+'SSOsess=300%7Cc6dc6d70vfvbf0891004364665f24b77; RTBk=300%7C451706342c67a37dfe5dede0b5d22469;
    ph03RPNCiscoASA=application.api.urlweb.com;
    ph04RPNCiscoASA=application.client.urlweb.com;'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can pass cookies string into `Cookie` inside `header` like this [DOCS](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/4d8a76f3691479ef22b55e05c07921af99332395/docs/Guide.md#managing-cookies)

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const cookiesString="cookie1=asdf; cookie2=dfasdfdas";   //here you can put your cookies
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          source={{
            uri: `${domain}`,
            headers: {
              Cookie: cookiesString,
            },
          }}
          style={styles.WebViewStyle}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  },
  WebViewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
});
```

Comment: Is there any way I could include a domain for each cookie? If I try `cookie1=asdf; ;domain=.domain.com;path=/;` this is being interpreted as 3 cookies.

Comment: @Shury sorry I did not understand you.

Comment: If I want to include a domain for each cookie such as `cookie1=asdf; domain=.domain.com; path=/; cookie2=asdasff; domain=.domain.com; path=/; cookie3=asfadf; domain=.domain.com; path=/; ` those would be interpreted as 9 different cookies instead of 3 (cookie + domain + path).

Comment: @Shury you have combined cookies of some domain. you can make a parser function to getting cookies for the specific domain. parser function will change this HTTP cookie to JSON formate then you have to filter cookie for the specific domain

Comment: I will award the bounty to you @Muhammad Numan in 5 hours when it's possible to give it as it answers my initial question. I'll have to see how to pass those extra attributes.

Comment: @Shury can I make a parser function for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226871/discussion-between-shury-and-muhammad-numan).